# Jquery Datatable : f is not defined in jquery.dataTables.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Jquery Datatables. I am getting f is not defined console error.
I am not using ajax request in Datatables.

Below is my Table:

```
<table id="myTable"  class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable"  >

    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Trip ID</th>
         <th>User Name</th>
         <th>From</th> 
         <th>To</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr><td>123231</td></tr>
     <tr><td>John</td></tr>
     <tr><td>dfshggsf</td></tr>
     <tr><td>dsfgfsgfsg</td></tr> 
   </tbody>
    <tfoot>
         <tr>
          <th>Trip ID</th>
          <th>User Name</th>
          <th>From</th> 
          <th>To</th>       
         </tr>
    </tfoot> 
        </table>    
</table>
```

Below is the Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#myTable').DataTable({

          'ordering':false,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',

            buttons:[
                 {
                     extend: 'excelHtml5',
                     title: 'Data export'
                 },
                 {
                     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                     title: 'Data export'
                 },
                  {
                     extend: 'csvHtml5',
                     title: 'Data export'
                 },
                  {
                     extend: 'print',
                     title: 'Data export'
                 } 
           ]
        });
    });
```

Below is the console error:

TypeError: f is undefined
[Learn More]
jquery.dataTables.min.js:27:64
jb
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:27:64
ga
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:48:224
e
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:92:256
m/<
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:92:342
each
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:370:10
each
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:137:10
m
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:82:457
h.fn.DataTable
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:164:289

http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/RajarathaTripHistory:38:4
fire
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:3232:11
fireWith
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:3362:7
ready
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:3582:3
completed
http://localhost:8080/RajaRathaDashBoardApp/resources/js/jquery-1.12.4.js:3617:3

Please help me solve this problem...Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How are you importing the jQuery datatables library?

Comment: @yarwest using script tag, <script  type="text/javascript"  src="resources/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you provide the entire console error?

Comment: @yarwest TypeError: f is undefined
[Learn More]
jquery.dataTables.min.js:27:64

Comment: Have you tried replacing the import of your local file with the online version? (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js)

Comment: Always use the _uncompressed_ version of a library (without `.min` in the filename) for debugging, for more readable errors and code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect table structure in `tbody` section.

Corrected table structure is shown below.

```
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td>123231</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>dfshggsf</td>
      <td>dsfgfsgfsg</td>
   </tr> 
</tbody>
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/5v5u5hkn/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

yup - that's how DataTables tells you that there is a mismatch in the table structure.  The most likely solution is to make sure that your `<th>` row matches your `<td>` row.

I ran into this last night when I noticed that last_name wasn't part of the DataTables search box.  DataTables searches against the field names provided in the column definition, not what is ultimately rendered out.  So I added the last_name column as visible: false thinking it wouldn't need a header.  Saw the same style error message and had to go back and add last to the header row = problem solved.

```
var columns = [

  { data: "first_name",
    render: function(data, type, row) {
      return row.first_name + " " + row.last_name;
    }
  },
  { data: "last_name",
    visible: false
  },
...
]
```